# Golang syscall.NewLazyDLL in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, go, system-calls

Is there any way to load the syscall.NewLazyDLL in Ubuntu?

I tried:

```
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-w -s" -o myFileName *.go
```

but the syscall.NewLazyDLL is not found.

```
var (
    mod               = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    procGetWindowText = mod.NewProc("GetWindowTextW")
)
```

My goal is to load the "windows" syscall functions, but from my main Ubuntu OS,
so I dont need to switch to Windows to code. Is there any way Ubuntu can call the Windows functions from syscall.NewLazyDLL or do I have to write code in Windows for this?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have to be on Windows, you are wanting to develop for Windows and not Linux using **syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")**.
Install a virtual machine.